# how to specifiy data-type "date" in jdbc-sink-connector schema information?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

- i am new to kafka-connect
- i want to write data from a kafka-topic to oracle, using the oracle-jdbc-sink-connector
- i can't use avro/schema-registry at the moment, so it must be JSON with schema-information inside the data-set
- a "hello world" data-set with simple data-types, like int, string, was written successfully to an oracle table, created via connector auto-create

now i am stuck, because i want to use a "date" data-type in my payload, **but i do not know how to specify that in the schema-information**.

here is the error message (connect-distributed.log)

```
ERROR WorkerSinkTask{id=oracle-sink-connector-0} Task threw an uncaught and unrecoverable exception (org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: Tolerance exceeded in error handler
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:178)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execute(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:104)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertAndTransformRecord(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.convertMessages(WorkerSinkTask.java:465)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.poll(WorkerSinkTask.java:321)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.iteration(WorkerSinkTask.java:224)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.execute(WorkerSinkTask.java:192)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:177)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:227)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Unknown schema type: org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.asConnectSchema(JsonConverter.java:528)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.asConnectSchema(JsonConverter.java:524)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter.toConnectData(JsonConverter.java:371)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.Converter.toConnectData(Converter.java:86)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.lambda$convertAndTransformRecord$2(WorkerSinkTask.java:488)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndRetry(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:128)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.errors.RetryWithToleranceOperator.execAndHandleError(RetryWithToleranceOperator.java:162)
        ... 13 more
```

and here is the relevant part of my JSON:

```
{"records":
    [{"value":  
        {"schema": 
            { "type": "struct", "fields": 
                [{"type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Date", "optional": false, "field": "BEZDAT"}
                ...]
                , "optional": false, "name": "foobar"}
        , "payload": {"BEZDAT": "2020-07-15"
        ...}}]}'
```

i also tried Date, 'Date', ´Date´, `Date`as *type*

According to the [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/5.1.0/connect/kafka-connect-jdbc/sink-connector/index.html) it is possible to use "date". But how to specify? Am i missing something?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution for this? I have a timestamp with ISO format and trying to find a solution.

Comment: @ArdaSavran unfortunately not, i went around by using "String" and let the database to the date-type-conversion stuff.